# When disconnecting a second monitor, my fullscreen app gets "covered" by the taskbar

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a .Net 4 WinForms application with the following properties on my `MainForm`:

- `FormBorderStyle` = None
- `WindowState` = Maximized

It works as expected and covers the entire screen. However, if a second monitor is disconnected while the application is open, the screen goes black while Windows is "removing" it, and then when the screen comes back, the application is resized so that it fits above the taskbar. I want the application to always be fullscreen and on top. Ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing that the application is losing focus.  Explorer is probably getting focus.  You could try setting your window as topmost.

Comment: What happens if your winforms app is on the second monitor when it is disconnected?

Comment: Have you tried setting TopMost = true ? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Setting the `TopMost` property to true does not help, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should `WindowState = Maximized` in the `onFocus` event of your MainForm.